# Java unexpected synchronization behaviour between actors using Akka framework

Tags: java, synchronization, locking, akka, pi

I recently learning the Akka framework in Java. When I practice with its starter tutorial, I encounter an interesting synchronization problem.

Basically my code uses two masters to calculate the Pi twice with the same precision. The difference is one masters will produce several Akka actors to calculate the Pi in parallel which the other master will calculate Pi in a traditional sequential way. This is for comparing performance.

```
package Citi.CAG.MIFID.AkkaTry;

import Citi.CAG.MIFID.Common.AppConfig.AppConfig;
import Citi.CAG.MIFID.Common.Log.LoggingHandler;
import akka.actor.*;
import akka.event.Logging;
import akka.event.LoggingAdapter;
import akka.japi.Creator;
import akka.japi.pf.ReceiveBuilder;
import akka.routing.ActorRefRoutee;
import akka.routing.RoundRobinRoutingLogic;
import akka.routing.Routee;
import akka.routing.Router;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;
import sun.rmi.runtime.Log;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Pi {

private static class Calculator {
    private final int index;
    private final int trunkSize;
    private double result = 0;
    private boolean isCalculated = false;
    public Calculator(int index, int size) {
        this.index = index;
        trunkSize = size;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public int getTrunkSize() {
        return trunkSize;
    }

    public void calculate() {
        for(int i = index * trunkSize; i < (index + 1) * trunkSize; ++i) {
            result += 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1);
        }
        isCalculated = true;
    }
}

private static class Slave extends AbstractActor  {

    private double calculatePiFor(int start, int nrOfElements) {
        double acc = 0.0;
        for (int i = start * nrOfElements; i <= ((start + 1) * nrOfElements - 1); i++) {
            acc += 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1);
        }
        return acc;
    }
    Slave() {
        receive(ReceiveBuilder.match(Calculator.class, msg -> {
            //msg.result = calculatePiFor(msg.getIndex(), msg.getTrunkSize());
            //msg.isCalculated = true;
            msg.calculate();
            sender().tell(msg, self());
        }).build());
    }

    static Props props() {
        return Props.create(Slave.class, Slave::new);
    }
}

private static class Master extends AbstractActor {

    private int resultCount = 0;
    private double result = 0.0d;
    private final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    private final ActorRef listener;
    private final Router router;

    public Master(ActorRef listener, int workerCount, int trunkCount, int trunkSize) {
        LinkedList<Routee> actorRefs = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < workerCount; ++i) {
            ActorRef ar = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(Slave.class), "Slave" + i);
            getContext().watch(ar);
            actorRefs.add(new ActorRefRoutee(ar));
        }
        router = new Router(new RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), actorRefs);
        this.listener = listener;
        receive(ReceiveBuilder.match(Calculator.class, msg -> !msg.isCalculated, msg ->
                IntStream.range(0, trunkCount)
                        .boxed()
                        .forEach(i -> router.route(new Calculator(i, trunkSize), self())))
                .match(Calculator.class, msg -> msg.isCalculated, msg -> {
                    result += msg.result;
                    resultCount += 1;
                    if(resultCount == trunkCount) {
                        Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                        listener.tell(result + " " + duration.toString(), self());
                        getContext().stop(self());
                    }
                }).build());
    }
}

private static class Listener extends AbstractActor {
    public Listener() {
        receive(ReceiveBuilder.match(String.class, msg -> {
            LoggingHandler.info(msg.toString());
            //akka system clean up code here, omi
        }).build());
    }

}

public void run() {
    final int workerCount = Integer.parseInt(AppConfig.getProperties("workerCount"));
    final int trunkCount = Integer.parseInt(AppConfig.getProperties("trunkCount"));
    final int trunkSize = Integer.parseInt(AppConfig.getProperties("trunkSize"));
    ActorSystem as = ActorSystem.create("AkkaTry");
    final ActorRef listener = as.actorOf(Props.create(Listener.class), "Listener");
    ActorRef master = as.actorOf(Props.create(Master.class, () -> new Master(listener, workerCount, trunkCount, trunkSize)), "Master");
    ActorRef master2 = as.actorOf(Props.create(Master.class, () -> new Master(listener, 1, 1, trunkCount * trunkSize)), "Master2");
    master.tell(new Calculator(0, 0), master);
    master2.tell(new Calculator(0, 0), master2);
}

public static void main() {
    new Pi().run();

}
}
```

In the above code, I have two approach of making calculation, one is calling the calculatePiFor() method in the Slave class, another is to call the calculate() method in the passed-in Calculator class. This slight difference produce significant performance difference.

```
private static class Calculator {
    private final int index;
    private final int trunkSize;
    private double result = 0;
    private boolean isCalculated = false;
    public Calculator(int index, int size) {
        this.index = index;
        trunkSize = size;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public int getTrunkSize() {
        return trunkSize;
    }

    public void calculate() {
        double result = 0.0d;
        for(int i = index * trunkSize; i < (index + 1) * trunkSize; ++i) {
            result += 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1);
        }
        isCalculated = true;
        this.result = result;
    }
}

private static class Slave extends AbstractActor  {

    private double calculatePiFor(int start, int nrOfElements) {
        double acc = 0.0;
        for (int i = start * nrOfElements; i <= ((start + 1) * nrOfElements - 1); i++) {
            acc += 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1);
        }
        return acc;
    }
    Slave() {
        receive(ReceiveBuilder.match(Calculator.class, msg -> {
            //msg.result = calculatePiFor(msg.getIndex(), msg.getTrunkSize());
            //msg.isCalculated = true;
            msg.calculate();
            sender().tell(msg, self());
        }).build());
    }

    static Props props() {
        return Props.create(Slave.class, Slave::new);
    }
}
```

If I call the calculation method in the Slave(actor), the performance is as expected: The parallel algorithm will finish in 1.719s while the sequential one finished in 6.745s

However, if I call the calculation method in the Calculator class passed in, the result will become 3.597s and 3.598s!!!
This behavior is quite weird, why this is happening???!~!!!

Comment: How do you measure the time? How do you mean "calling the calclation method in the slave actor"? That's private

Comment: In Slave actor, I have a private double calculatePiFor(int start, int nrOfElements) method. When slave actor receives the message, I can choose to call this private method or call the calculate method in the message class.

Comment: In master I have the time measurement code, on initialization get the currentTime, when all messages have been replied, calculate the duration